# Array is ignoring post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

Lost on why array looks like it's ignoring post type. I have a blog post that went up today that's not in this list at all, seems like it's pulling from any categorized content and not just blog post. I'm trying to get the most recent blog post and what category they're in.

Thanks!

```
    <div class="sidebar-blog-section">
    <h5 id="sidebar-categories">Categories <span class="mobile-only blog-toggle"></span></h5>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <ul class="sidebar-categories-list">
        <?php $args = array(
            //'show_option_all'    => 'View All Categories',            
            'orderby'            => 'date',
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'style'              => 'list',
            'post_type'          => 'post',
            'post_status'        => 'publish',
            'show_count'         => 1,
            'hide_empty'         => 1,
            'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
            'child_of'           => 0,
            'feed'               => '',
            'feed_type'          => '',
            'feed_image'         => '',
            'exclude'            => '',
            'exclude_tree'       => '',
            'include'            => '',
            'hierarchical'       => 1,
            'title_li'           => '',
            'show_option_none'   => '',
            'number'             => 6,
            'echo'               => 1,
            'depth'              => 0,
            'current_category'   => 0,
            'pad_counts'         => 0,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category',
            'walker'             => null
        ); ?>
    <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
            <li><a href="/categories">View All Categories</a></li>
        </ul> </div></div>
```

Comment: An array cannot ignore anything. It is a passive data structure.

Comment: You speak of a new post that is not showing, but you post code that lists categories, not posts?

Comment: Yeah I want the categories to be listed of the most recent published post. So today I posted something with the category 'SAL' but it doesn't show up in the list.

Comment: `wp_list_categories` does not accept `post_type` as an argument since it's a function to list terms based on a taxonomy (category). Are you just trying to show the categories that are attached to the post?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks @disinfor I didn't know that. Yes what would be my goal is to display the categories of the most recent published post. Is wp_list_post a thing?